# How to change jQuery panel href?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, href, panel, bind

I have an  record with an href to a panel. In differing states, I would like the button to open different panels.  I've tried changing the href, but that doesn't appear to be enough, as the button always opens the original panel.

The a record is defined like this ...

```
  <li><a href="#panel1" id="Xpanel" class="icon fa-crop">&nbsp;</a>
```

When clicked, panel1 is displayed and works great ...

I'm changing the href for the a record like so ...

```
   var id = document.getElementById('Xpanel');
   $(id).attr('href', "#panel2");
```

In the Safari debugger, I can see that all is changing, but the button always opens the original #panel1.

Do I need to rebind the  records href somehow ???

Comment: `document.getElementById('XPanel')`  you have a case difference between your link id and your lookup id if that is accurate

Comment: $('#Xpanel').attr('href','#panel2'); if yout html is accurate...

Comment: Show the code that 'opens the panel'.

Comment: Oh, that was just me typing it by hand .... case is same I'll edit the original post

Comment: This assigns the event
      var $panels = $('.panel');
      $panels.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
          $toggles = $('[href="#' + $this.attr('id') + '"]')
            .on('---show', function() {
              // Hide other content.
                if ($body.hasClass('content-active'))
                  $panels.trigger('---hide');
              // Activate content, toggles.
                $this.addClass('active');
                $toggles.addClass('active');
              // Activate body.
                $body.addClass('content-active');
            })

Comment: The thing is that all the panels get this type of initialization, and I'm trying to flip between 2 panels.

Comment: @carter, did you find any of the answers below helpful? If so, upvote them for their effort, and mark one as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating an event listener on `Xpanel` with a locally scoped variable, i.e. `Xpanel`'s `href` at the time. If you update the `href` the event listener doesn't use the updated value when it fires; it uses the original value when the listener was created.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to grab your element with `document.getElementById()`, and then again with jQuery. Based on your markup, the code below should work:

```
// Use jQuery's id selector
$("#Xpanel").attr('href', "#panel2");
```

If the code above isn't sufficient, then I would be looking at the event that fires off the code above. Is it being called before the use clicks the link?

Take a look a [jQuery's selector docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
var id = $('#XPanel');
id.attr('href', "#panel2");
```